# A buffer overrun has occurred in c++

Tags: c++, buffer-overrun

This program will get a string (char Array) of a math expression from the user and parse it then save each part(numbers and operators separately) in an element of an array called exp.I debugged this program before in c# and it worked quite properly but from now as I am studying C++ in college I have to program in this language so when I debug this program in visual studio I get an error that says:

"A buffer overrun has occurred in LineCalculator.exe which has corrupted the program's internal state. Press Break to debug the program or Continue to terminate the program."

please help, what should I do?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

struct str{
    char text[10];
};
void input();
void CurrentObs(char source[],char current , int i,str exp[],int c,int ExpNum);
void ExpAssign(int i ,int c , int ExpNum,char current ,char source[],str exp[]);
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    input();
    return 0;
}
void input()*//for getting the string from the user*
{
    char source[50];
    gets(source);
    struct str exp[20];
    int i=-1;
    int c=0;
    int ExpNum=-1;
    do{
        i++;
        char current=source[i];
        CurrentObs(source,current,i,exp,c,ExpNum);
    }while(i<50);
    //the next loop will print the parsed expressions in separate lines
    for(int b=0;b<20;b++)
        cout<<exp[b].text<<endl;
}
//the next function is to check if the current character is one of the signs mentioned in the signs array or not
void CurrentObs(char source[],char current , int i,str exp[],int c,int ExpNum)
{
    struct str signs[7]={"+","-","/","*","=","(",")"};
    for (int x=0;x<7;x++)
        if (current==*signs[i].text)
        {
            ExpNum++;
            ExpAssign(i,c,ExpNum,current,source,exp);
            break;
        }
}
void ExpAssign(int i ,int c , int ExpNum,char current ,char source[],str exp[])
{
    char parsed[10];
    for (int j = c; j < i; j++)
        parsed[j-c]=source[j];
    strcpy(exp[ExpNum].text,parsed);
    c=i+1;
```

Comment: break and see the line in the call stack where your program crashed. That's debugging.

Comment: Your code listing seems incomplete (maybe just a closing brace, but would I know?).  And @DavidKern is right; you need to track down WHERE the error is occurring.

Comment: Probably your strcpy does something nasty. Use std::string instead (or strncpy, if you insists on C)

Comment: how big is the string you are shoving into `source`?

Comment: Press Break to debug the program, obviously.